# Drupal 7 Change of View depending on domain

Tags: database, drupal, content-management-system

Is it possible in drupal 7 (and any other drupal versions) to have a SHARED DATABASE for 2 sites and the views would change depending on the subdomain / the URL.
Please see the illustration below.

[image]

All I want is to have a shared database for multiple site but with multiple view depending on the sub / domain it is accessed and modules / themes scope such as Captcha module should only be visible in the site2.

I'm stuck with this part. My second option is to have 2 database but only 1 database for accessing my site-specific data but for the segregation of content management data I think it would be best if I would have separate database as well for controlling access for modules. Let me know your thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Drupal DB abstraction and configuration setup is flexible enough to do the scenario you are going for. You will have to deal with users, then again here too it is a question of choice as Drupal allows you to share users or have different userland for each site.  There is a book out there on this subject, and many sites to assist in the various multi-site scenario options.

By the way, you can always post your D questions in drupal.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily solved with **Panels** as you can just choose the right Views view from there.

*There is no reason not to use panels on any drupal site imo.*